# Decoding a complex JSON correctly using Golang

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse a JSON from a URL. But I'm facing a problem while decoding values. Some are correct and the others are nil (empty strings or nil values for float64).

The JSON fetched from the URL is like this:

```
{
    "status":"success", 
    "data":{ 
        "coin":{ 
            "name":"Bitcoin",
            "abbr":"BTC",
            "logo":"",
            "homepage":""
        },
        "volume":{
            "current":15967300,
            "all":21000000,
            "perc":76.03
        },
        "markets":{
            "btce":{ 
                "name":"BTC-e",
                "last_update_utc":"2016-11-05T01:25:02Z",
                "value":694.696,
                "currency":"USD",
                "daily_change":{
                    "value":"699.05600000",
                    "perc":-0.62,
                    "diff":-4.36
                }
            },
            "coinbase":{
                "name":"Coinbase",
                "last_update_utc":"2016-11-05T01:25:02Z",
                "value":705.65,
                "currency":"USD",
                "daily_change":{ 
                    "value":"700.87000000",
                    "perc":0.68000000000001,
                    "diff":4.78
                }
            }
        },
        "last_block":{ 
            "nb":437388,
            "time_utc":"2016-11-05T01:27:32Z",
            "nb_txs":570,
            "fee":"0.06545766",
            "difficulty":"253618246641.490000000000000"
        },
        "next_difficulty":{ 
            "difficulty":255675205724.12,
            "retarget_in":84,
            "retarget_block":437472,
            "perc":0.81104538410295
        },
        "websocket":{
            "ws_url":"ws:\/\/btc.blockr.io:9081",
            "wss_url":"wss:\/\/btc.blockr.io:8081"
        }
    },
    "code":200,
    "message":""
}
```

My Go structs are:

```
type ResponseInfo struct {
    Status  string  `json:"status"`
    Data    Info    `json:"data"`                       
    Code    float64 `json:"code"`
    Message string  `json:"message,omitempty"`
}

type Info struct {
    Coin      _Coin      `json:"coin"`                  
    Volume    _Volume    `json:"volume"`                
    Markets   _Markets   `json:"markets"`               
    LastBlock _LastBlock `json:"last_block"`            
    NextDiff  _NextDiff  `json:"next_difficulty"`       
    WebSocket _WebSocket `json:"websocket"`             
}

type _Coin struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Abbr     string `json:"abbr"`
    Logo     string `json:"logo"`
    HomePage string `json:"homepage,omitempty"`
}

type _Volume struct {
    Current float64 `json:"current"`
    All     float64 `json:"all"`
    Perc    float64 `json:"perc"`
}

type _Markets struct {
    Btce     _BtceInfo     `json:"btce"`                
    Coinbase _CoinbaseInfo `json:"coinbase"`            
}

type _BtceInfo struct {
    Name        string     `json:"name"`
    LastUpdate  string     `json:"last_update_utc"`
    Value       float64    `json:"value"`
    Currency    string     `json:"currency"`
    DailyChange _BtceDaily `json:"daily_change,omitempty"`      
}

type _BtceDaily struct {
    Value string  `json:"value"`
    Prec  float64 `json:"prec"`
    Diff  float64 `json:"diff"`
}

type _CoinbaseInfo struct {
    Name        string         `json:"name"`
    LastUpdate  string         `json:"last_update_utc"`
    Value       float64        `json:"value"`
    Currency    string         `json:"currency"`
    DailyChange _CoinbaseDaily `json:"daily_change"`
}

type _CoinbaseDaily struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Prec  float64 `json:"prec"`
    Diff  float64 `json:"diff"`
}

type _LastBlock struct {
    Nb         float64 `json:"nb"`
    Time       string  `json:"time_utc"`
    NbTxs      float64 `json:"nb_txs"`
    Fee        string `json:"fee"`
    Difficulty string `json:"difficulty"`
}

type _NextDiff struct {
    Difficulty    float64 `json:"difficulty"`
    RetargetIn    float64 `json:"retarget_in"`
    RetargetBlock float64 `json:"retarget_block"`
    Perc          float64 `json:"perc"`
}

type _WebSocket struct {
    Wsurl  string `json:"ws_url"`
    WssUrl string `json:"wss_url"`
}
```

My incorrect output is:

```
{success {{Bitcoin BTC  } {1.59675375e+07 2.1e+07 76.04} {{BTC-e  694 USD { 0 0}} {Coinbase  704.2 USD { 0 0}}} {0  0  } {0 0 0 0} { }} 200 }
```

Edit1: 
Sorry the ouput my change because i'm parsing directly from the URL (http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/coin/info)

Edit2:
Thanks to @John S Perayil who found the mistake.
My JSON Tags need to be `json:"<name>"` not `json="<name>"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your json tags need to be `json:"<name>"`  not `json="<name>"`

Comment: Yes ! You're right. it works like expected.
I'm sorry i'm currently trying to learn go. Thanks again.